# Script para modificar textos da Bíblia (acessibilidade)

Tags: python, regex

Não sou programador. Pesquiso recursos de acessibilidade em função da minha baixa visão.

Estou tentando desenvolver um fluxo de trabalho que localize no documento textos bíblicos no padrão "João 3:16" e o transforme em "João, capítulo 3, versículo 16". A ideia é fazer com que um leitor de tela pronuncie de forma mais compreensível essa informação.

Na realidade, não preciso desse recurso, mas um amigo com uma visão bem mais limitada que a minha precisa. Como ele vai fazer um curso bíblico especial, quero adaptar o material, que é bem extenso, para ele.

Minha plataforma é o iOS e uso nele um app, chamado Editorial, que permite a execução de scripts Python.

Se alguém puder ajudar serei muito grato. A ideia é disponibilizar esse fluxo para outras pessoas portadoras de deficiência visual.

Comment: Oi pessoal. Me desculpem pela falta de precisão, se foi o caso. Mas o app que uso permite usar das dua formas, ou seja, um script python completo ou um fluxo "find & replace" individual. O que for mais produtivo. Grato desde já.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<nome>[^\s]+) (?P<capitulo>[^:]+?):(?P<versiculo>[^\s]+)")
s = "João 3:16"
m = pattern.search(s)
print m.group('nome') + ", capítulo " + m.group('capitulo') + ", versículo " + m.group('versiculo')
```

> João, capítulo 3, versículo 16

[IdeOne](http://ideone.com/ONqfaL)

Answer (score 2):

Aqui tem um script em Python 3.1 que faz o que você precisa, ele pode ser melhorado, mas assim funciona bem.

Eu tentei explicar como ele funciona nos comentários, se não der pra entender comente aqui em baixo que eu vou melhorando a explicação. Se tiver algo errado me avise também que eu vou consertando.

```
import re #Importa o módulo de regex

original = "João 3:16" #Entrada do script

index = re.search('\d', original).start() #Define index como a posição que a regex encontrar o primeiro dígito

nome = original[: index - 1] #Captura a string até o primeiro dígito (-1 serve para remover o espaço)
cap = original[index : re.search(':', original).start()] #Obtém o número do capítulo - pega da string desde o primeiro dígito (index) até antes de ':' 
ver = original[re.search(':', original).start() + 1: ] #Obtém o número do versículo - uma posição depois de ':' até o final

final = "{nome}, capítulo {capitulo}, versículo {versiculo}".format(nome = nome, capitulo = cap, versiculo = ver)

print(final)
```